# pyautogui.locateOnScreen() Returns... Nothing?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm trying to use PyAutoGui's image recognition functions. (OS X)

Needless to say, I'm running into some slight issues that I can't seem to solve myself no matter where I look or what I do. I'm attempting to have PyAutoGui click on the Chrome shortcut based off a .png screenshot saved to my desktop.

Here's my code in terminal:

```
>>>import pyautogui
>>>chrome = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('/Users/ianscalzo/Desktop/chrome.png")
>>>
```

I get no backfire on my filepath, but it causes my shell/terminal to return nothing but go to a new line. (As shown in the code example above - Just causes terminal to go to a blank ">>>")

I don't really understand why it doesn't do anything but go to a new line, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You assigned it to something, and assignment is a statement; statements aren’t expressions, so nothing will show up after performing one. What ends up in `chrome`?

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this forever also, finally figured out that you either use command line to take the screenshot or using the screenshot button with windows key. It doesn't work with the snipping tool.

so try:

```
image = pyautogui.screenshot()
image.save('testing.png')
```

Go and crop testing.png as small as possible so that locateOnScreen works faster. Then go back to the terminal and type:

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('testing.png')
```